# Reshape Data where measure id measure variables need to be paired and then defined by multiple id variables in new column

Tags: r, reshape2

I have the following data frame that looks like this:

```
  NA   X.nm.    X.A. Reaction.Type Trial Actual.Total.Seconds    RA
   1   300  3.3294          0ng      1               14.784 NaDithio
  51   350  0.1779          0ng      1               14.784 NaAsc
  81   380  0.1000          50ng     2               14.784 NaAsc
 101   400  0.0509          0ng      1               14.784 NaAsc
 151   450  0.0125          0ng      2               14.784 NaAsc
 201   500  0.0054          0ng      2               14.784 NaDithio
 251   550  0.0026          0ng      1               14.784 NaDithio
 301   600  0.0010          50ng     1               14.784 NaAsc
 351   650 -0.0001          0ng      1               14.784 NaAsc
 381   680 -0.0005          0ng      1               14.784 NaAsc
```

So there is a column for "Reaction.Type", "Trial", "Actual.Total.Seconds", "RA", "X.nm", "X.A". Please ignore column Na.

I want to reformat my data frame so that there is a new X.nm. and X.A. (which are paired) column for every combo of ("Reaction.Type", "Trial", "Actual.Total.Seconds", "RA"). I want the title of each column as the combo. Every X.nm. has a corresponding X.A (kind of like a coordinate point, for every X.nm, there is a X.A. that goes with it)

Example:
Column 1 title: X.nm from 0ng, 1, 50seconds, NaAsc (this will have another column that matches the X.nm to the X.A.)

Column 2 title: X.A. from 0ng, 1, 50seconds, NaAsc

*Then do this for every combo like below, so there'd be more columns for each combo

```
  X.nm. from 0ng, 1, 14.784seconds, NaDithio    X.A from 0ng, 1, 50seconds, NaDithio
    300                                         3.3294   
    550                                          0.0026
```

When I try to use recast() from reshape2 package, it doesn't keep the X.A. and X.nm pairs together.

Please help! Thank you.

Comment: Please include data as plain text, not images, so users can copy/paste. You can include the output of `dput(df1)` or if too large, `dput(head(df1))`.

Comment: What do you mean by " it doesn't keep the X.A. and X.nm pairs together"?

Comment: It makes the X.A. and X.nm. as 2 variables in one column so they're no longer paired like a coordinate pair

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)
df2 <- df %>% 
   unite(var, c(Reaction.Type, Trial, Actual.Total.Seconds, RA)) %>% 
   gather(var2, val, -var, -NA.) %>% 
   unite(var3, c(var2, var)) %>% 
   spread(var3, val)

df2[,split(names(df2), c(1, rep(2:7, 2))) %>% unlist]

#    NA. X.A._0ng_1_14.784_NaAsc X.nm._0ng_1_14.784_NaAsc
# 1    1                      NA                       NA
# 2   51                  0.1779                      350
# 3   81                      NA                       NA
# 4  101                  0.0509                      400
# 5  151                      NA                       NA
# 6  201                      NA                       NA
# 7  251                      NA                       NA
# 8  301                      NA                       NA
# 9  351                 -0.0001                      650
# 10 381                 -0.0005                      680
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but it gives me an error: Duplicate identifiers for rows and then will list rows that don't even exist in the original dataframe?

Comment: Duplicate identifiers? `dcast` would probably work better in that case.